# Ingress Nginx throwing a client request body is buffered to a temporary file warning

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

We have an ingress resource hostname say `xyz.int.com` setup on two k8s cluster A and B. The ingress controller used is nginx. On DNS we have setup `xyz.int.com` to point to the loadbalancer IPs in respective clusters.

For some strange reason, in one cluster I'm getting the below warning and not getting any status code for request if its a success or not:

```
2022/01/17 17:58:00 [warn] 13239#13239: *94097411 a client request body is buffered to a temporary file /tmp/client-body/0001505726, client: 10.9.8.0, server: xyz.int.com, request: "POST /api/vss0/an/log/83f740daa89b3d3638b37a6a06de49a59f1f5126129a9a6?clientTimeInMs=1642442284833&sdkV=811409&gpid=a15e3b7c2-e1366-4327d-83a93-f7619&devNet=WIFI&locale=en-IN&region=IN HTTP/1.1", host: "xyz.int.com"
```

Whereas the same endpoint in another cluster works fine, and there is no explicit difference in both the nginx controller or ingress resource.

What can be the issue? Kindly assist.

Comment: That's not an error. That just means the POST body was larger than nginx's internal buffer. Things should still function correctly, even with the warning. If your ingress is not working, the error is elsewhere.

Comment: @jordanm it is functioning as expected.

Comment: @SanjayM.P., since everything is functioning as expected - there is no issue anymore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summarizing the comments:

This warning message means that the size of the uploaded file was larger than the in-memory buffer reserved for uploads.

Please refer to [this description](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#client_body_buffer_size) explaining how `client_body_buffer_size` works:

> Sets buffer size for reading client request body. In case the request body is larger than the buffer, the whole body or only its part is written to a temporary file. By default, buffer size is equal to two memory pages. This is 8K on x86, other 32-bit platforms, and x86-64. It is usually 16K on other 64-bit platforms.